# Unable to install MKLpy?

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, pip, conda, svm

I am trying to install a python library named **'MKLpy'**. Yesterday I tried from Spyder shell by the command`'pip install MKLpy'`. That Library is of size 758MB! Nevertheless , It started to download but at the near to the ending the PC was paused and I forced the PC to shut down. Today I again did the same thing but it even didn't starts to download. It shows

```
 pip install MKLpy
Collecting MKLpy
  Using cached MKLpy-0.5.2.tar.gz (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from MKLpy) (1.18.1)
Collecting torch
Killed
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I also have tried by the command `pip3 install MKLpy` at Ubuntu terminal but it fails every time while downloading. Here it is ...

```
(base) subhajit@subhajit-Aspire-ES1-572:~$ pip3 install MKLpy
Collecting MKLpy
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/44/356e014828e89938439b45287d82641770d4d19013f9585fd7bc885686f3/MKLpy-0.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting cvxopt (from MKLpy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/da/385b85d3ef47e72a242abe304a03cea098cb9ba6cdb795b044e8c7806b18/cvxopt-1.2.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy (from MKLpy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/16/476826a84d545424084499763248abbbdc73d065168efed9aa71cdf2a7dc/numpy-1.19.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting scikit-learn (from MKLpy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/3a/eb8d7bbe28f4787d140bb9df685b7d5bf6115c0e2a969def4027144e98b6/scikit_learn-0.23.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting torch (from MKLpy)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/01/457b49d790b6c4b9720e6f9dbbb617692f6ce8afdaadf425c055c41a7416/torch-1.5.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (753.2MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 753.2MB 671kB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

So , where is the problem and how to install that library? Here is the github link of **MKLpy**
//github.com/IvanoLauriola/MKLpy. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not strictly related to the library but to your system.
Are you using Jupyter? In this case, you may consider to restart it.

Honestly, I do not know how to fix the pip3 error, I just wanted to specify that 758MB is not the dimension of MKLpy but the size of PyTorch, that is one dependency of MKLpy.

Comment: Ohh! I was using spyder IDE. Nevertheless now I'm using Google Colab , there are no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Steps to follow :

1. Open Anaconda
2. Go to environments . Select the base(root) environment .
3. In the dropdown menu , select "Not installed".
4. Select pyMKL ( The name varies according to the versions used) .
5. Click apply at the bottom right corner of your screen .
6. If a new pop up window opens , click Ok.
7. It will be successfully installed.]
   View this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYc3.jpg) for help